Is there a way to write joining where clauses without AND operator?
Just for curiosity, is there a short/pretty way to write classic SQL where clauses without the AND operator for joining tables?
Classic:
select * 
from table1, table2, table3 
where table1.fkId = table2.id 
  and table1.fkId = table3.id

It would be nice to have something like:
select * 
from table1, table2, table3 
where table1.fkId = table2.id = table3.id

For info, I am using Oracle and SQL Server databases most of the time.

Out of curiousity, why would you want old join syntax? Use contemporary join syntax. select a.id, b.name from table1 a join table2 b on a.id = b.id

Sure, don't use a WHERE at all here, "upgrade" to the ANSI-92 syntax; it has been about for 32 years after all.

@ThomA, there is a host of reasons why native Oracle SQL is still in use (a lot). There are plusses and minuses to both syntaxes.  Oracle has never stopped supporting their own native syntax just because they support the industry standard as well. It's largely a matter of preference, though in OP's case given that they use a mix of Oracle and MS SQL, probably the ANSI syntax makes more sense.

I think the old hat syntax has mostly minuses, because it's very easy to mess up and turn it into a cross join, only upside is that it's a bit less verbose, also the *= stuff have own problems

Can be done, where (table1.fkId, table1.fkId) = (table2.id, table3.id) - but still a bad idea - switch to explicit JOIN syntax.

You can use the ALL operator for the same
select * from table1, table2, table3 
where table1.fkId=ALL(table2.fid,tables3.fid..)


SQL Server doesn't accept a comma delimited list values for ALL. The values need to be provided by a sub query

ISO/ANSI SQL syntax error.

If you just want to avoid the AND keyword then you can use the ANSI join syntax:
SELECT * 
FROM   table1
       INNER JOIN table2
       ON table1.fkId = table2.id
       INNER JOIN table3 
       ON table1.fkId = table3.id

Don't do this, but you can also mix the legacy comma-join syntax with the ANSI-join syntax if the ANSI joins are first:
SELECT * 
FROM   table1
       INNER JOIN table2
       ON table1.fkId = table2.id,
       table3 
WHERE  table1.fkId = table3.id

SQL Server Fiddle Oracle Fiddle
